# How to select a record consisting of single JSON response from a Sharepoint list using C#?

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint

I am trying to extract a single JSON response record from a SharePoint list. There can be multiple records but I need to select only a single record at a time from the SharePoint list. At present, I am fetching all data and then iterating on it but this is not what is required. I am using Newsoft Json to deserialize the response.

Code:

```
    HttpWebRequest endpointRequest =   (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url); endpointRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["singlesionuserid"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ItservicesPassword"].ToString());
        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest
            .GetResponse();

        Stream receiveStream = endpointResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader
            (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>
            (readStream.ReadToEnd());

        foreach (var item in results.d.results)
        {
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject inputJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(item.CreatedBy);

            // Read Properties of the JObject
            var properties = inputJson.Properties();

            foreach (JProperty property in properties)
            {

                url = property.Value.ToString();
                var successList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateByURI>(url);
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using the CSOM API? And why raw HttpWebRequest instead of HttpClient? You could replace all of this code with 2-3 lines using HttpClient or a *single* method call with the client API.

Comment: Right now you have 50 lines simply to make a call with the wrong URL. The Client API allows you to specify a query, generates the correct URL and deserializes the response.

Comment: Finally, all list items or documents have an ID. You can get them if you use the correct URL, which typically contains the list name and ID. Or you can use [List.GetItemByID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee546240.aspx) from the client SDK

Comment: How would CSOM API help me to fetch a single row from the list? I need values of all the columns of that particular row. I have no primary key situation.

Comment: Read the previous comment. A single call to `GetItemByID` would retrieve the item. Besides, even if you wanted to execute raw HTTP calls you can use the OData SDK to make the appropriate calls instead of all this

Comment: BTW you didn't post the *url*. If it contained an ODATA query that returned a single item by ID you wouldn't have to loop. It would also return strongly-typed items.

Comment: I have approx 15 columns and I am retrieving the rows on the basis of the value of one column. For example, all rows having that value as "xyz" would be retrieved. In this case, I don't know the value of ID column and hence can't use GetItemByID .

Comment: Then use the CSOM or ODATA SDK to write a query. Both will produce a URL with the query. The important part in this question is the URL, not how you deserialize the response. BTW querying is covered in the docs

Comment: After checking the REST API examples I understood where you copied that code from. Let's say that SharePoin'ts documentation wasn't created by C# experts. Anyway, check [How to: Retrieve List Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx) which shows how to execute a query. If you want to filter items, you *have* to use CAML. If you only want to limit the fields returned you can use `CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(int,string[])` to specify a row limit and field list

Comment: Also check [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#select-fields-to-return). The URL to return specific fields is `http://server/site/_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$select=Title,Products/Name&amp;$expand=Products/Name`

Comment: To filter, you'd add eg `;$filter=Title eq 'That Title'`

Answer (score 0):

We can use CSOM API to get a single list item.

Here is a demo for your refernce.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointFoundation.Samples
{
  class List_getItemByIdExample
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Web site = clientContext.Web;
        List targetList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

        // Get the list item from the Announcements list whose Id is 4. 
        // Note that this is the ID of the item in the list, not a reference to its position.
        ListItem targetListItem = targetList.GetItemById(4);

        // Load only the title.
        clientContext.Load(targetListItem,
                         item => item["Title"]);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Request succeeded. \n\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved item is: {0}", targetListItem["Title"]);
    }
  }
}
```

More information about CSOM API for your reference.
[SharePoint CSOM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)